# Is this correct way to deploy springboot cloud netflix in production on multi host network?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, docker-network

I am developing a spring boot application with netflix cloud stack. and deploying each module(microservice) in separate docker container. Structure is as follows:

1. Eureka
2. Zuul
3. Business logic in Microservices
4. MySQL
5. Angular4 UI
6. Keycloak - User management and Authentication
7. ELK - for log maintenance
8. Hystrix
9. Zipkin

Okay so after facing lot of problems and spending whole lot of network bandwidth on googling on the matter I have deployed in following way, What I need to know is, if it is correct way to do it ?

The limitation here is that I have been provided with 2 hosts to test this configuration and further action plan is not there yet.

So here is what I have done: I have not yet used full stack which I mentioned.

**Server 1**

1. Eureka
2. Zuul
3. ELK

**Server2**

1. Keycloak
2. Business Logic microservices
3. MySQL
4. Anguar4 UI

Haven't configured and used Hystrix and Zipkin yet. 
So I have given the IP:PORT of the Server1 in the Eureka configuration of all the microservices which needs to register on Eureka. Same goes for Zuul(given the IP:PORT of Eureka).

In the Angular4 UI I have given the URL:PORT of Zuul deployment, because all the services will be called through Zuul.

This I understand is correct because Services needs to know where Eureka is located and rest can be managed through Eureka.

Now my key question is, because MySQL, ELK can't be registered on Eureka, so is it correct to give IP:PORT of MySQL and ELK wherever required ?

Same goes with the configuration of ELK, with ELK my requirement is also that all the logs are located at common place for this I have used docker, volume mounting but I don't know how to accomplish this on multi host environment, I can only make dockers out put logs on external volume which can then probably be accessed by ELK over URL, haven't tested this configuration yet.

If so then isn't this configuration not so Independent if we think it will be able to manage itself ?

I have configured my docker compose to use "network_mode": host so host to host docker communication can be done.

Again All I need to know is, is my configuration/architecture correct for multi-host environment and in future for Cloud environments ? 
If Not, then please kindly guide me to correct path.

Thank you!
p.s. excuse me for my English and Grammar, I have tried best to my knowledge to make it understandable, please point out and ask questions if you need more input from my side.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question is really beyond the scope of Stackoverflow, but it really sounds like you haven't come to understand the pieces of your infrastructure yet.

The Netflix stack (Eureka/Zuul etc) and things like Zipkin, Hystrix and the whole ELK stack only start to make sense when you have really large deployments of many services in multi-site, with many hosts where managing "by hand" becomes a real problem, where you have a lot of moving parts in the architecture where something can break and your system still needs to keep running, like a host disconnects or a database node dies.

With 2 hosts and a couple of services it doesn't make sense to introduce all this complexity, it will just overwhelm and confuse you (it already has). If one of your 2 hosts dies even if you're using Eureka and Zuul and it will not save you. The whole system will go down.

Throw out all those latest buzzword libraries (you're not Netflix yet) and just think through a simple architecture where you will run your services say on one host and database on another host (no need for Eureka or Zuul). Think of a shared location for logs and organise a nice, easy to use folder structure to store them so they're easy to find and search with simple command line tools that are much better than Kibana (which is TERRIBLE to look at logs).

Stay simple and only introduce new pieces when you feel it is getting difficult to manage.

Comment: Actually the project is going to be big, Currently I am in learning stage, Just need to know how to work on this stack properly, I have a team of Me+3 people who are going to work on this. We plan to bring in Kubernetes in it, but that is second step, and for deployment pipeline we are going to use Jenkins so pretty much things are planned but I want to do it step by step and understand each layer practically by working on it.

Comment: my advice still stands. Keep it simple until you have a need to introduce additional complexity. Which ALL of those things above add.